# How to include external js file in joomla 3.8

Tags: php, joomla3.0

How to Including external js file in `joomla 3.8` in different articles and modules.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to include a JavaScript file using the Joomla API. The first is to use the JDocument class of the addScript method:

```
 <?php
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
    ?>
```

2- 
The second uses the JHTML class of the script method

```
<?php
// Add the path parameter if the path is different than 'media/system/js/'
JHTML::script('sample.js', 'templates/custom/js/');
?>
```

API has changed in 3.x, so the second parameter cannot be a string. If you really need to use this method, you must include the absolute link to your JavaScript file:

```
<?php
JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/custom/js/sample.js');
?>
```

hope this help you .

Comment: Thank you for your time Mohammed,could you please tell me in which file we need to add this code.

Comment: but i think in your case , you are looking for to import in the module so ,
There are three methods for embedding JavaScript into your code using the Joomla API: JDocument :: addScriptDeclaration, JDocument :: addScript, and script. These methods must be called either in your Component view <yourcomponent> / views / <yourview> /view.html.php or by a template script <yourcomponent> / views / <yourview> / tmpl / <yourtemplate> .php or in the case of a module, in its template script <yourmodule> / tmpl / <yourtemplate> .php.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed

Comment: can you check my answer if it's helpful for you please

Comment: I have checked it out.
But there is one more way we can add external js files.
While adding article we can provide add external js file in the code editor itself, 
I'm using jck editor in that editor we have to change the configuration settings by allow external js files.

Comment: and what happen if you don't allow that , you are not going to add js files every time you add an article .

Comment: We cannot add the external js files  if you  won't configure the option to allow

Comment: so the problem still in that way

Comment: I don't find any problem in that way , I  can able to add external js files to each article.!

Comment: so , there is no problem if i understand

Comment: Yes there is no problem, I'm using Joomla 3.8